# Oracle SQL -- find the values NOT in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Take this table WORDS

```
WORD
Hello
Aardvark
Potato
Dog
Cat
```

And this list:

```
('Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Greetings', 'Dog')
```

How do I return a list of words that AREN'T in the words table, but are in my list?

If I have a table that "contains all possible words", I can do:

```
SELECT * from ALL_WORDS_TABLE
where word in ('Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Greetings', 'Dog')
and word not in 
(SELECT word from WORDS
where word in ('Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Greetings', 'Dog')
);
```

However I do not have such a table. How else can this be done?

Also, constructing a new table is not an option because I do not have that level of access.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Instead of hard coding the list values into rows, use `DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL` to dynamically convert your delimited list into rows, then use the `MINUS` operator to eliminate rows in the second query that are not in the first query:

```
select column_value 
from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Greetings', 'Dog'))
minus
select word
from words;
```

Comment: Nice technique ) But what if access to sys.* functions is denied?

Comment: @denied Well that would be awkward indeed. There may be other ways to convert a delimited list of strings into a column that is more elegant than sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll. Perhaps there is a solution using pure SQL?

Comment: @Denied In this context, `sys` is not a bad thing.  Someone could theoretically deny you access to that type, but it's probably not something you need to worry about.  It's about as likely as someone removing access to `sys.dbms_output`.

Comment: Works perfectly and very clean. Thank you!

Comment: Really neat way to get result that was not part of the table values. I used to do it using a UNION for each value and it was long. This is much better.

Comment: @Wolf, I tried your answer on mine but it returns an error: `ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`. Here is my query: `SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS not_loaded FROM TABLE(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('12345','54321')) MINUS SELECT column_name FROM table_name;`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is there a solution where in case if i have 4-5k strings to check instead of 4 we could use something similar as currently the ORACLE restricts more than 1000 arguments in the dbms_debug_vc2coll() and throws an ORA-00939: too many arguments for function
00939. 00000 -  "too many arguments for function"

Answer (score 5):

You can turn your list into a view like this:

```
select 'Hello' as word from dual
union all
select 'Goodbye' from dual
union all
select 'Greetings' from dual
union all
select 'Dog' from dual
```

Then you can select from that:

```
select * from
(
    select 'Hello' as word from dual
    union all
    select 'Goodbye' from dual
    union all
    select 'Greetings' from dual
    union all
    select 'Dog' from dual
)
where word not in (select word from words);
```

Possibly not as neat a solution as you might have hoped for...

You say you don't have sufficient privileges to create tables, so presumably you can't create types either - but if you can find a suitable type "lying around" in your database you can do this:

```
select * from table (table_of_varchar2_type('Hello','Goodbye','Greetings','Dog'))
where column_value not in (select word from words);
```

Here `table_of_varchar2_type` is imagined to be the name of a type that is defined like:

```
create type table_of_varchar2_type as table of varchar2(100);
```

One such type you are likely to be able to find is `SYS.KU$_VCNT` which is a TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000).

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution :

```
SELECT
 a.word
FROM
(
 SELECT 'Hello' word FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT 'Goodbye' word FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT 'Greetings' word FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT 'Dog' word FROM DUAL
) a
LEFT JOIN ALL_WORDS_TABLE t ON t.word = a.word
WHERE
 t.word IS NULL
```